# Python Script Not Starting Bash Script when running as service

Tags: bash, systemd, python

I have a python script that get started automatically as a service (activated with systemd). In this python script, I call a bash script using `subprocess.call(script_file,shell=True)`.

When I call the python script manually (`$ python my_python_script.py`), everything works perfectly. However, the automatically started program does not execute the bash script (however it does run, I checked this my making it edit a text file, which it indeed does).

I (think) I gave everyone read-write permissions to the bash scripts. Does anyone have ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Addendum: I want to write a small script that sends me my public IP address via telegram. The service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=IPsender
After=networking.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/projects/tg_bot
ExecStart=/home/pi/miniconda3/bin/python /home/pi/projects/tg_bot/ip_sender_tg.py
Restart=always


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Does the python script need to fully-path the bash script?

Comment: How, exactly, does the python script call the bash script?

Comment: I use os.getcwd() to get the correct path to the bash script.

Comment: Sounds like an environment problem: there's something in your environment that is not in the daemon's environment. Do you use absolute paths to call the shell script? Do you rely on any environment variables?

Comment: import subprocess
...
subprocess.call'('.../my_script.sh',shell=True)

Comment: Have you verified that `getcwd()` returns what you think it does?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, I've printed it to a text file, it gives the correct location of where the bash scripts are stored.

Comment: Is SELinux preventing the execution, I wonder?

Comment: Then you need to use a relative path when you call the script: `call("./myscript.sh")`

Comment: @glennjackman What do you mean? I concatenate the entire path and the script name, and give that as the argument, i.e., it looks something like subprocess.call('/home/pi/.../myscript.sh',shell=True)

Comment: Given your question, how are we supposed to know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protawn, welcome to the Unix and Linux StackExchange.

Why scripts work differently under system is a common question. Check out [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339638/difference-between-systemd-and-terminal-starting-program/339645#339645) to the general question elsewhere on the site.

Without the source code for your Python and Bash scripts it's hard to guess which difference you have encountered.

My personal guess is that your `bash` script is calling some other binaries without full paths, and those paths are found in your shell `$PATH` but not the default systemd `path`.

Add `set -x` to the top of your bash script so that all actions are logged to standard out, which will be captured in the `systemd` journal. Then after it fails, use `journalctl -u your-service-name` to view the logs for your service to see if you can find the last command that bash executed successfully.   Also consider using `set -e` in the bash script to have it stop at the first error.

Despite the two "off-topic" "close" votes on this topic, why things work differently under systemd is on topic for this Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I'm not sure an Answer is warranted yet, if you're guessing and not sure how the OP is calling the script.  The output of `set -x` and `journalctl` would be clarifying comments.